# Installing Scrapy-Python and Easy_install on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, installation, scrapy, easy-install

I'm trying to install Scrapy on windows 7. I'm following these instructions:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/intro/install.html#intro-install

I’ve downloaded and installed python-2.7.5.msi for windows following this tutorial https://adesquared.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/setting-up-python-and-easy_install-on-windows-7/, and I set up the environment variables as mentioned, but when I try to run python in my command prompt I get this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>python
‘python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\> python ez_setup.py install
‘python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

Could you please help me solve this?

Comment: `ur` is python2 syntax, you are trying to install a package meant for python2 not python3

Comment: I don't understand, could you please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ur` is python2 syntax you are trying to install an [incompatible](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-work-with-python-3) package meant for python2 not python3:

```
_ajax_crawlable_re = re.compile(ur'<meta\s+name=["\']fragment["\']\s+content=["\']!["\']/?>')
                                 ^^ python2 syntax
```

Also pip is installed by default for python3.4

Comment: I uninstalled Python 3 and downloaded version 2.7.5 But when I try to run Python from cmd I get this error: ‘python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: you need to add it to your path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: how did you install python?

Comment: I downloaded python-2.7.5.msi from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and run the installer

Comment: Did you check to see if there is a Python directory?

Comment: Sure, it is C:/Python27

Comment: I restarted the system and it worked thanks :). Now I'm  having problem in creating a new project, could you please check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166053/unable-to-start-new-scrapy-project

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy doesn't work with Python 3 as mentioned in their [FAQ](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-python-versions)

you should install Python 2.7

Comment: I uninstalled Python 3 and downloaded version 2.7.5 following this tutorial: 
https://adesquared.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/setting-up-python-and-easy_install-on-windows-7

But when I try to run Python from cmd I get this error: ‘python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I think you should update your PATH environment variable, check the answer here (its for win 7 but should  be ok for 8 as well): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: After ending up here and realizing scrapy does not work with python 3, I finally succeeded installing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Step By Step way to install scrapy on Windows 7

1. Install Python 2.7 from [Python Download link](https://www.python.org/downloads) (Be sure to install Python 2.7 only because currently scrapy is not available for Python3 in Windows)
2. During pyhton install there is checkbox available to add python path to system variable click that option. Otherwise you can add path variable manually.
   You need to adjust PATH environment variable to include paths to the Python executable and additional scripts.
   The following paths need to be added to PATH `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;`
   [image: windows add path variable]

If you have any other problem in adding path variable please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)
3. To update the PATH open a Command prompt in administration mode and run: `:\python27\python.exe c:\python27\tools\scripts\win_add2path.py`.Close the command prompt window and reopen it so changes take effect, run the following command, to check ever thing added to path variable. 
`python -–version` which will give output as `Python 2.7.12` (your version might be different than mine) 
 
`pip --version` which will give output as `pip 9.0.1` (your version might be different than mine)
 4. You need to install visual basic C++ Python complier. You can download that from [Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
 5. Then you install to install libxml which python library used by scrapy. You download it by writing a command `pip install libxml` into command prompt.
but if you face some problem in pip installation you can download it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml *download **libxml** package according to your system architecture*. Open command prompt into that download directory and `pip install NAME_OF_PACKAGE.whl` 
 6. Install pywin32 from [Download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). *Be sure you download the architecture (win32 or amd64) that matches your system* 
 7. Then open command prompt and run this command `pip install scrapy`

I hope this will help in successful installing scrapy
 8. For Reference use can your these links [Scrapy official Page](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) and [Blog on how to install scrapy on windows](http://www.blog.thoughttoast.com/crawling/scrapy/install-scrapy-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

**How to install Scrapy 1.4 on Python 3.6 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64**

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
mkvirtualenv my_scrapy_project
```

I advice to use virtualenv. In my example I am using name *my_scrapy_project* for my virtual environment.
If you want to go out of virtualenv, simply type **deactivate**, if you want to go back into, simply type **workon *my_scrapy_project***.

- Go to: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
- Click on button: Download Visual C++ Build Tools 2015
- Install these tools.
- Go to: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml
- Find and download: lxml-4.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
- Move this file to your active directory in commandline and install it:

`pip install lxml-4.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`

```
pip install scrapy
```

And that is all, it should work.