# Unable to start new Scrapy Project

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, easy-install

I'm new to scrapy, I installed Python 2.7.5 on windows 7. When I run startproject I get this error:

```
C:\>scrapy startproject new
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 612, in _build_ma
ster
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 918, in require
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 805, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: cryptography>=0.2.1
```

I tried updating scrapy, but I still get this error. Please help!!

Comment: Update your python to 2.7.9 and then install.

Comment: did you `pip install cryptography`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update python 2.7.9 and then install.

(this was previously a comment.)