# Installing Scrapy windows 7

Tags: windows, installation, scrapy, lxml, pyopenssl

I am trying to install Scrapy by the official Scrapy guide at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

In the said guide it mentions you need 4 pieces of software to be already installed to go through the installation. So I successfully installed Python 2.9.10, installed 'pip.' And checked they were installed by 'python/pip --version,' checking method suggested in Scrapy installation guide.

However I am very confused about how to install point 3 which is 'lxml' and point 4 'pyOpenSSL.'

For point 3 there is another complex installation guide (http://lxml.de/installation.html). If I don't have 'static binary distribution' then I need to download 2 more files, which I went ahead and downloaded and the installation is totally unclear, its just like a bundle of random file names, my computer doesn't even recognise the '.rpm' files. Usually there is an '.exe' file that you just click and its simple.

For point 4 also I hit a dead end. Not sure how to install OpenSSL file, just like those in point 3.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Scrapy-Python and Easy\_install on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150433/installing-scrapy-python-and-easy-install-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy for any one else who has this problem.

You make sure you have pip installed and then you open windows powershell and navigate it to the directory with pip. You can use [pip -list] at any time to see what programs you have currently installed (in Python).

Then you just do 'pip install lxml', and then 'pip install pyOpenSSL'. Powershell will look and find the files from the official python website and then install them by itself. You can check aswell by using 'pip -list' to see if you have successfully installed it or not. Then you just do 'pip install scrapy'. 
Not hard if you know what to do but very little support and very strange for someone who has never used Python before.